# Covariance between a vector $X$ and its norm $\lVert X \rVert$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

As stated in the title, I need an expression for the covariance between the elements of a vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, and its norm $\lVert X \rVert$.

There is a formula for the covariance between $X$ and $\lVert X \rVert^2$, as I wrote in [the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/624386/covariance-of-quadratic-form-and-a-random-vector-of-type-mathbfg-mathbfy/630117#630117) to another question, which seems to be an easier case due to the lack of the square root, but I can't find anything for $\lVert X \rVert$. I'm not sure what approach I could take to try to derive such an expression myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.